# Why does applicatication context often not switch between apps using screens?

Tags: dock, screen, desktop

Since I've been using Mavericks (currently I'm on ElCap) I have am a heavy user of screens insofar I actually use different desktops for different apps to reduce the ammount of clutter on my individual desktops and so I can use both Which, Dock, or follow hyperlinks, to switch between desktops which are used exclusively for an app. I realize for cases where I use an app on more than one desktop, when you switch to that app it will take you to the desktop that was last used for that app. What I am finding however is that doing things like following links within certain apps, it does NOT take me to my default browser (Chrome) on the last desktop I was using. In fact, I often find it does nothing and I have to manually go to the desktop I was just using. The new page loads there, but that's about it. This can bee annoying when I am running around 8 desktops. Any ideas why this would happen? Thought at first the machine was lagging and waited for it to "catch up" but it never did. Any ideas why might be causing this lack of function?

Comment: Do you have apps fixed to specific Spaces? I've found that Finder can lose track periodically, making clicking the Desktop not go back to [in my case] Space 1. It usually happens if I ever carry a window over to another Space manually.

Comment: Yes most apps are bound to dekstop numbers, and context switching normally seem honored which this is the case. It is when the app is on a desktop but is not there explicitly because of screen options is when it doesn't change context. Again, this is not consistent either- sometimes ti works and sometimes not. It's Definitely more a problem with Chrome.